# Questions on Mathematica

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

A Mathematica question just came up and I answered it.

Someone asked that it should be deleted as off-topic.

There is a 'mathematica' tag in MSE, which was used in this question.

Also, there is a new SE for Mathematica.

Are we saying that we want to remove all Mathematica related questions from MSE and have them answered at the Mathematica SE?

Thank you.

Comment: We probably don't want to remove all the *existing* Mathematica related questions from here; that sounds like a lot of work! We can still decide that *from now on* Mathematica questions should be migrated to the Mathematica site. I noticed that [a Mathematica question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/292364/856) was closed without being migrated, and that seems unfortunate.

Comment: @ℝⁿ. I actually flagged this for migration, perhaps the flag was cleared when the question was closed and no moderator saw that.

Comment: Some small number of Mathematica questions may also be mathematics questions.  In that case, choose the group most appropriate for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question is a Mathematica question, the natural place for it is the site dedicated to Mathematica.

Comment: @MarianoSuárezAlvarez: Thanks, not a problem as that makes sense. So, should we remove the 'mathematica' tag from MSE and then forward all MMA questions to the MMA SE? Regards.

Comment: @Amzoti MSE has a large number of questions which are correctly tagged `mathematica` and were satisfactorily answered here.  There is no compelling reason to migrate old, answered questions. And as long as they are here, they should be properly tagged.

Comment: @Amzoti: To add on 5PM's comment old threads cannot be migrated anymore. So it's not even possible to move away all the Mathematica questions.